# How to append a property to a Json object inside a Json Array?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I have the following variable holding a json array.

```
let requestJson = '{ "data": [ { "type": "Type1", "value": "MyValue" } ] }';
```

I would like to add a property called "Id" to the above object inside data array. I expect to get something like;

```
{ "data": [ { "type": "Type1", "value": "MyValue", "id": "123" } ] }
```

How can I achieve this? I tried the following:

```
requestJson["data"][0]["id"] = '123';
```

But when I print `requestJson["data"]` I'm getting `undefined`. Would appreciate any help in appending the "Id" attribute to the object inside the array above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: requestJson is a string, not an object. Use JSON.parse(requestJson) first (or eliminate the outer single quote marks). Also, you can do `requestObj.data[0].id = '123'`

Comment: and of course [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: @pilchard did refer to that question but I was confused since I had to append to the object inside the array, instead of updating the array with a new object. Thanks

Comment: @AnOldSoul your access attempt was correct, it was just the parsing that you were missing

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse your string to convert it to an Object and after that you can manipulate the `data` attribute

```js
let requestJson = '{ "data": [ { "type": "Type1", "value": "MyValue" } ] }';
const parsedObject = JSON.parse(requestJson)
parsedObject.data[0].id = 1
console.log(parsedObject)
```